# how to use rich web text editor in coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion-8, cfml, rich-text-editor

How does one use a rich web text editor in coldfusion? 
is there any website from where i can get and use code for "rich web text editor" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you are looking for a [WYSIWYG
  editor](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/full.php) that end users could
  utilize on your website, likely in
  conjunction with a textarea object,
  then [checkout TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/).
- If you are looking for a ColdFusion
  IDE, your best bet is utilizing the
  [Eclipse IDE](http://www.eclipse.org/) with the [CFEclipse
  plugin](http://cfeclipse.org/). An Adobe based IDE is also available called [CFBuilder](http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion/cfbuilder/features/), though this route is not free.

Comment: thanks for answering me, i am looking for rich text editor that provides facility to admin of any website to change their website content without opening its source code but by the facility of rich text editor of their website.